# How does iChat start a conversation?

Tags: xmpp, p2p, sip, ichat

I want to know which protocol does iChat use to start a conversation with other client in LAN ?
is it SIP? or SIP + XMPP? 
start a session with SIP and exchange message with XMPP?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses [Bonjour](http://www.apple.com/support/bonjour/), XMPP but using [multicast DNS](http://www.multicastdns.org/) for presence, and peer-to-peer connections instead of a server. The protocol was designed by Apple and then openly documented by the [XMPP Standards Foundation](http://xmpp.org/) as [XEP-0174: Serverless Messaging](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html).

Comment: thank you very much, so now we can discover the presence service with the help of jmdns(provides DNS-SD), we know name@host:port. but the problem is how to start a conversation with the client knowing its name@host:port? Is there any suitable library in java? like smack(but smack donesn't support P2P), any library for serverless messaging? I don't want to do the encapsulation for data frame.

Comment: I looked at XEP-0174 and tried to establish a socket connection to the bonjour client, and send the string "<stream:stream ...", but got the exception pipe broken, is what I tried to do correct? or something was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So, I understand how does ichat work now. DSN-SD + XEP-0174.
unfortunately there isn't any java library for XEP-0174, but the connection is based on socket.
thanks for everyone's attention.